# localize the module wide variable with the same variable name

Tags: python

I tried to localize a module wide variable to the definition in the module, but I got `UnboundLocalError` and was confused with the reason raising the error. For example, the following codes are implemented in the module `test.py`

```
# implementation 1
a=5
def geta():
    a=a
    return a
```

Import and run:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.geta()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    test.geta()
File "test.py", line 3, in geta
    a = a
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

But the following ways work.
First one is to define as default value of the input variable `a`:

```
# implementation 2
a=5
def geta(a=a):
    return a # return 5
```

And the second one is to use different name in the definition:

```
# implementation 3
a=5
def geta():
    b=a
    return b # return 5
```

Why I can't localize the variable `a` using **implementation 1** with the same name? Why it raises the error `referenced before assignment` in **implementation 1** but works in **implementation 3**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a variable after it is already defined in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369408/how-to-change-a-variable-after-it-is-already-defined-in-python)

Comment: @Josh If the most voted answer of your posted question is true, why **implementation 3** works?

Comment: In implementation 3, the variable `a` is a global variable, because you don't assign to it within the function. In implementation 1, `a` is a local variable, because you do assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# implementation 1
a=5
def geta():
    global a
    a=a
    return a
```

You have to make a global variable