# Is python reading the next line of code in advance

Tags: python-3.x, scope, global-variables

```
var = "Old world"
class a(object):
    def b(self):
        print(var)
        #var = "Updated world"      
aObj = a()
aObj.b()
```

When I run the above code it works fine.
But when i uncomment line 5 `var="Updated World"` it throws UnboundLocalError on line 4.
I understand that i cannot modify *var* at line 5. But why I'm getting an error at line 4. Any good inputs are welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a variable after it is already defined in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369408/how-to-change-a-variable-after-it-is-already-defined-in-python)

Comment: Python is in fact parsing and compiling the entire file before it executes even a single line of it.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh The question is different only the syntax matches. please try to understand it well. Thanks for replying soon.

Comment: @Learner1947 I do understand it.  As in the question I linked, you're trying to reference the value of a local variable before assigning it.  When you remove the assignment line, then `var` never refers to a local variable, so it is determined to be a global variable instead.  Did you read the answer to the question I linked?  It explains why you are encountering this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python parser reads the entire file before executing even a single line of it. At the time a function is `def`ined, its body is parsed and Python decides on what symbols (variable names) refer to what. If it sees any *assignment statement* inside the function, it takes the assignee to be a *local variable*; unless you explicitly override that with the `global` or `nonlocal` keywords. If there is no assignment statement in the function body, the variable is inherited from the outer scope.