# Instead of having a global scope why the following code shows error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I already declare b = 6 globally. But why this code shows an error instead of printing b = 6.But when I delete b = 33 inside that is inside the function the code works well & print b = 6. But why?

```
b = 6
def f(a):
      print(a)
      print(b)
      b = 33

f(20)
```

Comment: Use `nonlocal b`...

Comment: Hi @John Zwinck,
I searched for it but can not find.
Can you help me with the link?
Because I am totally new here.

Comment: @John Zwinck I don't think that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function. This asks about a specific behaviour, not about the use of globals in general.

Comment: @Insomniac: it is, and of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369408/how-to-change-a-variable-after-it-is-already-defined-in-python. The OP really should have *at least* included the error message in their question.