# How to fix two object same name 'local variable referenced before assignment' Error in Python

Tags: python, function, local

I defined one function, and in the function or another function I assign the same-name value by call the same-name function. I get this  error

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'demo01' referenced before assignment

The error occurs here

```
def demo01():
    return 5

def demo02():
    demo01=demo01()

demo02()

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'demo01' referenced before assignment
```

But these snippets are fine

```
def demo01():
    return 5

def demo02():
    demo01=demo01()

demo01 = demo01()
```

```
def demo01():
    return 5

def demo02():
    demo02=demo01()

demo02()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a variable after it is already defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369408/how-to-change-a-variable-after-it-is-already-defined)

Comment: In `demo2` what do you think the name `demo1` denotes?

Comment: I think there are different questions, thank U.

Comment: In demo2，first demo01 is a local variable, and the second demo01 is one function name.

Comment: Yes @CraigMeier they are different questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is an existing variable, creating a new one under that name will overwrite the existing variable, for example:

```py
print = 2 # change the print() function to a variable named 2
print('string')
```

will give

```py
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

going back to your code:

```py
demo01 = lambda: 5 # this is more of an advanced keyword, feel free to do it your way

def demo02():
    demo01 = demo01() # "demo01 = [val]" tells python to assign a value to demo01, and you cannot assign a variable to the same variable:
```

```py
variable = variable
```

obviously not possible; gives

```py
NameError: name 'variable' is not defined
```

when used in a global state and UnboundLocalError when used in a local (class or function).

Your variable names and other variables, if any, used during assignment ***MUST NOT BE OR REFERENCE THE VARIABLE YOU ARE CURRENTLY ASSIGNING***.

If you really need to use the same variable:

```py
variable_ = variable()
variable = variable_
```

Comment: Should I regard as "the variable name demo01 is same name as function demo01()'s name demo01"？ U use variable=variable, it's same as variable_name=variable_name() ?

Comment: `variable = variable()` if you try this when variable is already defined, then `TypeError: type(obj).__name__ is not callable` the first part of `variable = ` overwrites `variable`'s function definition. You need to use different names for them.