# Python UnboundLocalError, what causes it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python I wrote:

```py
registered_to = 0

def execute_data():
    registered_to += response.text.count("<div class=\"info-msg\">")
```

But I'm getting:

```
registered_to += response.text.count("<div class=\"info-msg\">")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'registered_to' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If yes, then please accept the answer by click on the tick mark icon just below the vote counter

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, have you understood the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a global variable from within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369408/how-to-change-a-global-variable-from-within-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
registered_to = 0

def execute_data():
    global registered_to
    registered_to += response.text.count("<div class=\"info-msg\">")
```

**global** keyword must be used whenever you wish to modify/create global variables from a non-global scope like a function. If you are just using a global variable from a non-global scope and not modifying it, you need not use the keyword.

**Examples**

1. Using global variable in a non-global scope but not modifying it

```
wish = "Hello "

def fun():
    print(wish)

fun()
```

2. Using global variable in a non-global scope and modifying it as well

```
wish = "Hello "

def fun():
    word += "World"
    print(wish)

fun()
```

Comment: why u defined it twice? it's already outside function

Comment: I want it to be global 0 and the function every time adds to it (and when it ends its value is always saved), your code won't do that

Comment: Check this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/

Comment: they did the same as I did in example 1

Comment: This is also useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python

Comment: @martin for modification of a global variable, you need to use global keyword. In the first example, they are just using it and not modifying it. See the 2nd example where they are modifying a globally declared variable in a function which has a local scope.